# Highchart IRREGULAR Spline with drilldown - cannot get drilldown functional

Tags: highcharts, spline, drilldown

I have been pulling my hair out trying to get this highcharts irregular spline with drilldown and couldnt get the drilldown to work.  I am new to highcharts and I think it may have to do with my syntax.  I have referenced the API and tried a few methods with no luck.

Problem:  I wanted to get a irregular spline to show counts of fruits by month.  The drilldown would then show counts for types of fruits (apples and oranges).  I am able  to show the counts of fruits but the drilldown is not working.

The codes is below and also here: http://jsfiddle.net/bu2002/352a0zvr/2/

THanks so much everyone!!!

$(document).ready(function() {

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'spline'
    },
     xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
            month: '%e. %b',
            year: '%b'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        }
    },
     yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'count'
            },
            min: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Fruits',
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2014,  7, 19),12],
            [Date.UTC(2014,  8, 19),5],
            [Date.UTC(2014,  9, 19),18]
        ],
        drilldown: 'fruits'
        },
        {
            name: 'Animals',
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(2014,  7, 29),15],
                [Date.UTC(2014,  8, 11),11],
                [Date.UTC(2014,  9, 22),38]
            ],
            drilldown: 'animals'
        }
    ],//end series
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
                id: 'animals',
                data: [[Date.UTC(2014,  7, 29),15],
                [Date.UTC(2014,  8, 11),11],
                [Date.UTC(2014,  9, 22),38]],
            },
            {
                id: 'fruits',
                data: [
                    [Date.UTC(2014,  7, 29),15],
                    [Date.UTC(2014,  8, 11),11],
                    [Date.UTC(2014,  9, 22),38]
                ],
            }
        ]
    }//end drilldown

};//and options

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

});

Comment: There is much wrong with your code. Dangling commas, brackets out of place, no drilldown.id to let the chart no what drilldown point is linked to a data point. Have a look at the basic drilldown examples first: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#drilldown

Comment: Thanks for your feedback wergeld!  I have edited to code and added the drilldown code.  I am still not getting any responses when clicking on the graph to drilldown.  The edited code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/bu2002/352a0zvr/5/

Comment: Because you still have not provided a drilldown id. Read the docs at the link I provided.

Comment: I have provided drilldown.IDs is in the drilldowns (line 45 annd 51 in jsfiddle) as shown in the basic drilldown examples.  Is there somewhere else I need to add?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is now that you are providing a `drilldown.id` on the series. You need to do it per point. For example:

```
 series: [{
            name: 'Things',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Animals',
                y: 5,
                drilldown: 'animals'
            }, {
                name: 'Fruits',
                y: 2,
                drilldown: 'fruits'
            }, {
                name: 'Cars',
                y: 4,
                drilldown: 'cars'
            }]
        }],
```

It looks to me like you want to have any drilldown on a point in "Fruits" to link to the same drilldown series. This is doable:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Fruits',
    data: [{
        x: Date.UTC(2014, 7, 19),
        y: 12,
        drilldown: 'fruits'
    }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2014, 8, 19),
        y: 5,
        drilldown: 'fruits'
    }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2014, 9, 19),
        y: 18,
        drilldown: 'fruits'
    }]
},
```

See update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/352a0zvr/6/).

Comment: Awesome!!! That's where I got hung up on - failing to associate my drilldown by point.  Much Much Much appreciated wergeld!

Comment: I also would like to know if the second part of the question is feasible: **when clicking on fruits,  can you drilldown to irrlegular graphs of apples and oranges?  Here is my updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bu2002/352a0zvr/10/

Comment: Yes. You make your drilldown series contain just the fruits you want.

Comment: I tried something like below but that just came out in one graph with the points named orange/apple. How can we associate multiple data objects for one drilldownID. I review the API but didnt find what I need. Is it feasible to have separate spline graphs drilleddown for apples and oranges when clickinng on the initial fruits graph? Thanks in advance for your help!

http://jsfiddle.net/bu2002/352a0zvr/10/

Comment: I have opened up a new issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948067/highchart-irregular-spline-with-drilldown-is-it-possible-to-do-multiple-irregu

Answer (score 0):

But here also U dont get 2 splines after clicking on fruits, u just get one.
Is there any way to get that as i have the same issue 
fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/surya_swami/zx9dy3uj/40/

```
drilldown: {  series: [{id:"z1",name: "Region-1",
                     data: [{ name : "July",y: 10},
                            { name : "Aug",y: 21},
                            { name : "Sept",y: 15}]
                     },
                     {id:"z1",name: "Region-2",
                      data: [{ name : "July",y: 12},
                             { name : "Aug",y: 9},
                             { name : "Sept",y: 25}]
                     },
                     { id:'z2',name:'Region-3',
                       data : [{name:'July',y:23},
                               {name:'Aug',y:41},
                               {name:'Sept',y:31}]
                     },
                     { id:'z2',name:'Region-4',
                       data : [{name:'July',y:33},
                               {name:'Aug',y:23},
                               {name:'Sept',y:12}]
                     },
                     { id:'z2',name:'Region-5',
                       data : [{name:'July',y:31},
                               {name:'Aug',y:39},
                               {name:'Sept',y:19}]
                     }
                    ]
        }
```